# Préposition pour/de: nom + pour/de + verbe

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, prépositions

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre la différence entre "pour" et "de" quand on a un nom + pour/de + un verbe:

> On a raison de/pour penser ce qu’on pense. Trois raisons de/pour penser ça.
>
> Tu devrais avoir assez de force de/pour résister.
>
> Elle trouvera la force de/pour résister à la tentation.
>
> Tu n'as pas le pouvoir de/pour me garder ici.

C'est pareil? Ou il y a des phrases qui sont incorrectes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De manière générale "nom + de + verbe" signifie que le nom est une circonstance du verbe ("36 façons de préparer les pâtes") et "nom + pour + verbe" signifie que la finalité du nom est le verbe ("la machine que j'utilise pour faire des pâtes"). Mais dans ces exemples il y a des "pièges" dus à des expressions.

> On a raison de/pour penser ce qu’on pense.

L'expression "avoir raison de" s'impose ici.

> 3 raisons de/pour penser ça.

Le sens de "raison pour penser ça" est incongru, un peu comme si on commandait ses raisons dans le but de produire une pensée prédéterminée. C'est l'inverse. On a des raisons qui nous poussent à penser d'une certaine manière. "De".

On pourrait en revanche dire quelque chose comme "*Il met en avant 3 raisons pour se justifier.*" si le but des raisons avancées est de se justifier.

> Tu devrais avoir assez de force de/pour résister.

L'expression "assez de X pour Y" indique la suffisance d'une quantité par rapport à ce qui est nécessaire pour l'atteinte d'un but, c'est donc clairement "pour" que l'on choisirait dans ce cas.

> Elle trouvera la force de/pour résister à la tentation.

"De". Quoique "pour" soit acceptable ici au sens de "rassembler la quantité de force nécessaire pour", mais colle mal avec "résister à la tentation" qui est plutôt un effort que l'on fait sur soi-même. Ce serait moins étrange d'utiliser "pour" dans ce sens si c'était "pour résister à l'envahisseur".

> Tu n'as pas le pouvoir de/pour me garder ici.

"De" dans ce cas. "Avoir le pouvoir pour me garder" présuppose l'existence possible d'un pouvoir dont l'objectif spécifique serait de me garder, et que tu n'aurais pas. Or le sens de la phrase est bien plus probablement celui de l'expression d'une non-possibilité de me garder en général.

Answer (score 3):

"Pour" indique un lien entre un effort et un but:

> J'ai assez de force pour soulever un rocher.
>
> Pour toi, je suis prêt à tout.

On ne peut pas l'utiliser quand la situation n'a rien à voir avec cela, notamment:

> On a raison pour penser ce qu'on pense.

signifierait

> On a eu raison pour pouvoir penser ce qu'on pense.

ce qui est très étrange.

De même:

> Tu n'as pas le pouvoir pour me garder ici.

signifierait

> Le but de ton pouvoir n'est pas de me garder ici.

"De" n'a pas de signification propre, c'est une préposition qu'on place souvent pour créer un groupe complémentaire, à un nom ou un verbe, et ainsi le préciser: "la force de résister" est plus précis que "la force", "avoir raison de penser XXX" est plus précis que "avoir raison", etc. On peut techniquement l'utiliser dans toutes les phrases de la question mais il est très maladroit dans certaines, notamment:

> Tu devrais avoir assez de force de résister.

Cela n'aurait de sens que dans un cadre où un personnage a plusieurs forces différentes, et là on parlerait de sa "force de résister".

(note que la phrase suivante passe beaucoup mieux avec "de", car le groupe nominal est moins ambigu et beaucoup mieux séparé du reste)

Comment: La phrase avec "assez" n'est pas comme les autres — c'est "pour" qu'il faut, pour produire l'expression "assez de ... pour ..." indiquant la suffisance d'une quantité. Tous les autres vont avec "de".

Comment: @qoba: Si tu as une autre réponse à proposer, fais-donc !

Comment: Bah je trouve que la tienne est très bien et mieux argumentée que ce que j'aurais la patience d'écrire mais bon... OK